# how to add recycler view into each fragment activity Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

normally in main activity we used this

```
private lateinit var recy: RecyclerView
private lateinit var userList: ArrayList<UserData>
private lateinit var userAdapter: UserAdapter



private fun setUp() {
   userList = ArrayList()
   userAdapter = UserAdapter(this, userList)
   recy = findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_mon)
   recy.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
   recy.adapter = userAdapter
   binding.addingButton.setOnClickListener { addInfo() }

}
```

but what if I want to implement this recycler view in the fragment activity, cause i want to reuse the recycler view in 5 fragment activity, and also used android binding , what should I replace the "this" word inside the UserAdapter(this, ), any suggestioin ? The error said that userList has not been initilized

```
private lateinit var userList: ArrayList<UserData>
private lateinit var userAdapter: UserAdapter
lateinit var binding: FragmentMondayBinding

 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    binding.recycleViewMon.layoutManager = layoutManager
    userAdapter = UserAdapter(context, userList)
    binding.recycleViewMon.adapter = userAdapter
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `lateinit` keyword for `userList`. That means you need to initialize it before using, but you don't do that, you using it directly like below:

`userAdapter = UserAdapter(context, userList)`

Instead make an empty list at the beginning. And for `this` keyword, you can user `requireActivity()`:

```
 private var userList = ArrayList<UserData>()
 private lateinit var userAdapter: UserAdapter
 lateinit var binding: FragmentMondayBinding

 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity())
    binding.recycleViewMon.layoutManager = layoutManager
    userAdapter = UserAdapter(requireActivity(), userList)
    binding.recycleViewMon.adapter = userAdapter
 }
```